# completionHandler in Swift4 return String

Tags: swift, asynchronous, completionhandler

I am trying to build a small currency converter and the problem is that my completionHandler does not work. As a result, the input Currency does not change instantly after the function was executed

I have already tried to implement a completionHandler; however, had no success yet

```
class CurrencyExchange: ViewController {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCurrency: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var segOutputCurrency: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtValue: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var segInputCurrency: UISegmentedControl!


    //Variables
    var inputCurrency: String!
    var currencyCNY: Double!
    var currencyEUR: Double!
    var currencyGBP: Double!
    var currencyJPY: Double!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }


    @IBAction func btnConvert(_ sender: Any) {
        assignOutput()

        if txtValue.text == "" {
            self.lblCurrency.text = "Please insert value"
        } else {
            let inputValue = Double(txtValue.text!)!
            if segOutputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex == 0  {
                    let output = Double(inputValue * currencyCNY!)
                    self.lblCurrency.text = "\(output)¥"
            }  else if  segOutputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                let output = Double(inputValue * currencyEUR!)
                self.lblCurrency.text = "\(output)€"
            }  else if  segOutputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                let output = Double(inputValue * currencyGBP!)
                self.lblCurrency.text = "\(output)"
            } else if  segOutputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
                let output = Double(inputValue * currencyJPY!)
                self.lblCurrency.text = "\(output)"
            }
        }
    }





    func assignOutput() {

        let currencies = ["EUR", "JPY",  "CNY", "USD"]
        inputCurrency = currencies[segInputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex]


        Alamofire.request("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=\(inputCurrency!)").responseJSON { (response) in
            let result = response.result
            let jsonCurrencies = JSON(result.value!)
            let dictContent = jsonCurrencies["rates"]
            self.currencyCNY = dictContent["CNY"].double
            self.currencyEUR = dictContent["EUR"].double
            self.currencyGBP = dictContent["GBP"].double
            self.currencyJPY = dictContent["JPY"].double
        }
    }   
}
```

The expected result is that everytime the btnConvert function is called the assignInput and assignOutput functions are called and the variables are set to the right values. I am a beginner so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your `assignInput` is only calling the `completionHandler` under 1 condition instead of under all conditions.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What IS happening? Any crash logs? Which bits of code are getting stuck? Have you printed out values at certain lines? Added breakpoints to check the code is running?

Comment: I know... I did not continue since Xcode throws the following error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Comment: If you only want to return a `String` in the completion handler, why define the completion handler to return a dictionary?

Comment: Why are you using a completion handler in `assignInput`? There's no need. Nothing is asynchronous. Just use a normal return value on the function.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) I will give it a try

Comment: Stop editing the code in your question, Jakob. You’re making previous comments invalid. Plus, even your text is referring to a method, `assignInput` that is no longer valid. If you want to supplement your question with additional code, that’s fine, but don’t edit your question in a way that makes comments and questions invalid. Bottom line, clarifying questions is fine, but changing them isn’t.

Comment: Sorry. My fault. Learned something new for the next time.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the hint. I will include AFNetworking. Nonetheless, it seems like I have to be more careful when it comes to unwrapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of a completion handler is that you have some asynchronous method (i.e., a method that finishes later) and you need to give the caller the opportunity to supply what it wants the asynchronous method to do when it’s done. So, given that `assignOutput` is the asynchronous method, that’s the method that you would refactor with a completion handler escaping closure.

Personally, I’d configure this escaping closure to return a `Result` type:

For example:

```
func assignOutput(completion: @escaping (Result<[String: Double]>) -> Void) {
    let inputCurrency = ...

    Alamofire.request("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=\(inputCurrency)").responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(error))

        case .success(let value):
            let jsonCurrencies = JSON(value)
            guard let dictionary = jsonCurrencies["rates"].dictionaryObject as? [String: Double] else {
                completion(.failure(CurrencyExchangeError.currencyNotFound)) // this is just a custom `Error` type that I’ve defined
                return
            }

            completion(.success(dictionary))
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could use it like so:

```
assignOutput { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    case .success(let dictionary):
        print(dictionary)
    }
}
```

By using `Result` types, you have a nice consistent pattern where you can check for `.failure` or `.success` throughout your code.

---

That having been said, I’d suggest a variety of other refinements:

1. I wouldn’t make this view controller subclass from another view controller, `ViewController`. It should subclass `UIViewController`.

   (Technically you can re-subclass your own custom view controller subclasses, but it’s exceptionally uncommon. Frankly, when you’ve got so much in your view controller subclass that you need to have subclasses of subclasses, it may be code smell indicating that you’ve got too much in your view controller.)
2. I’d give this view controller a class name that unambiguously indicates the type of object, e.g. `CurrencyExchangeViewController`, not just `CurrencyExchange`. This habit will pay dividends in the future, when you start breaking these big view controllers into something more manageable.
3. You have the list of accepted currencies in four different places:

   - In your storyboard for `segOutputCurrency`
   - In your storyboard for `segInputCurrency`
   - In your `btnConvert` routine
   - In your `assignOutput` routine

   This makes your code brittle, making it easy to make mistakes if you change the order of the currencies, add/remove currencies, etc. It would be better to have a list of currencies in one place, programmatically update your `UISegmentedControl` outlets in `viewDidLoad` and then have your routines all refer back to a single array of which currencies are permitted.
4. You should avoid using the `!` forced unwrapping operator. For example, if the network request failed and you then reference `result.value!`, your app will crash. You want to gracefully handle errors that happen outside of your control.
5. If you’re going to format currencies, remember that in addition to currency symbols, you should consider that not all locales use `.` for decimal place (e.g. your European users may use `,`). For that reason, we would generally use `NumberFormatter` for converting the calculated number back to a string.

   Below, I’ve just used `NumberFormatter` for the output, but you really should use it when interpreting the user’s input too. But I will leave that to the reader.
6. There’s a more subtle point when dealing with currencies, above and beyond the currency symbol, namely how many decimal places the result should display. (E.g. when dealing with Japanese yen, you generally don’t have decimal places, whereas euros and US dollars and would have two decimal places.)

   You can write your own conversion routine if you want, but I might associate the chosen currency codes with `Locale` identifiers, that way you can leverage the symbol and the number of fractional digits appropriate for each currency. And I’d format the string representations of numbers using `NumberFormatter`s.
7. The convention for outlet names is usually some functional name followed by the type of control. E.g. you might have `inputTextField` or `currencyTextField` and `outputLabel` or `convertedLabel`. Likewise, I might rename the `@IBAction` to be `didTapConvertButton(_:)`
8. I’d personally excise the use of SwiftyJSON, which, despite the name, feels unswifty to me. I’d use `JSONDecoder`.

Pulling that all together, you might end up with something like:

```
//  CurrencyViewController.swift

import UIKit
import Alamofire

// types used by this view controller

struct Currency {
    let code: String              // standard three character code
    let localeIdentifier: String  // a `Locale` identifier string used to determine how to format the results
}

enum CurrencyExchangeError: Error {
    case currencyNotSupplied
    case valueNotSupplied
    case currencyNotFound
    case webServiceError(String)
    case unknownNetworkError(Data?, HTTPURLResponse?)
}

struct ExchangeRateResponse: Codable {
    let error: String?
    let base: String?
    let rates: [String: Double]?
}

class CurrencyExchangeViewController: UIViewController {

    // outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputCurrencySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputCurrencySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    // private properties

    private let currencies = [
        Currency(code: "EUR", localeIdentifier: "fr_FR"),
        Currency(code: "JPY", localeIdentifier: "jp_JP"),
        Currency(code: "CNY", localeIdentifier: "ch_CH"),
        Currency(code: "USD", localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        updateCurrencyControls()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapConvertButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let inputIndex = inputCurrencySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        let outputIndex = outputCurrencySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex

        guard inputIndex >= 0, outputIndex >= 0 else {
            resultLabel.text = errorMessage(for: CurrencyExchangeError.currencyNotSupplied)
            return
        }

        guard let text = inputTextField.text, let value = Double(text) else {
            resultLabel.text = errorMessage(for: CurrencyExchangeError.valueNotSupplied)
            return
        }

        performConversion(from: inputIndex, to: outputIndex, of: value) { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                self.resultLabel.text = self.errorMessage(for: error)

            case .success(let string):
                self.resultLabel.text = string
            }
        }
    }

    func updateCurrencyControls() {
        outputCurrencySegmentedControl.removeAllSegments()
        inputCurrencySegmentedControl.removeAllSegments()

        enumerateCurrencies { index, code in
            outputCurrencySegmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: code, at: index, animated: false)
            inputCurrencySegmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: code, at: index, animated: false)
        }
    }
}

// these might better belong in a presenter or view model rather than the view controller

private extension CurrencyExchangeViewController {

    func enumerateCurrencies(block: (Int, String) -> Void) {
        for (index, currency) in currencies.enumerated() {
            block(index, currency.code)
        }
    }

    func errorMessage(for error: Error) -> String {
        switch error {
        case CurrencyExchangeError.currencyNotFound:
            return NSLocalizedString("No exchange rate found for those currencies.", comment: "Error")

        case CurrencyExchangeError.unknownNetworkError:
            return NSLocalizedString("Unknown error occurred.", comment: "Error")

        case CurrencyExchangeError.currencyNotSupplied:
            return NSLocalizedString("You must indicate the desired currencies.", comment: "Error")

        case CurrencyExchangeError.valueNotSupplied:
            return NSLocalizedString("No value to convert has been supplied.", comment: "Error")

        case CurrencyExchangeError.webServiceError(let message):
            return NSLocalizedString(message, comment: "Error")

        case let error as NSError where error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain:
            return NSLocalizedString("There was a network error.", comment: "Error")

        case is DecodingError:
            return NSLocalizedString("There was a problem parsing the server response.", comment: "Error")

        default:
            return error.localizedDescription
        }
    }

    func performConversion(from fromIndex: Int, to toIndex: Int, of value: Double, completion: @escaping (Result<String?>) -> Void) {
        let originalCurrency = currencies[fromIndex]
        let outputCurrency = currencies[toIndex]

        fetchExchangeRates(for: originalCurrency.code) { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))

            case .success(let exchangeRates):
                guard let exchangeRate = exchangeRates.rates?[outputCurrency.code] else {
                    completion(.failure(CurrencyExchangeError.currencyNotFound))
                    return
                }

                let outputValue = value * exchangeRate

                let locale = Locale(identifier: outputCurrency.localeIdentifier)
                let string = formatter(for: locale).string(for: outputValue)
                completion(.success(string))
            }
        }

        /// Currency formatter for specified locale.
        ///
        /// Note, this formats number using the current locale (e.g. still uses
        /// your local grouping and decimal separator), but gets the appropriate
        /// properties for the target locale's currency, namely:
        ///
        ///  - the currency symbol, and
        ///  - the number of decimal places.
        ///
        /// - Parameter locale: The `Locale` from which we'll use to get the currency-specific properties.
        /// - Returns: A `NumberFormatter` that melds the current device's number formatting and
        ///            the specified locale's currency formatting.

        func formatter(for locale: Locale) -> NumberFormatter {
            let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
            currencyFormatter.locale = locale

            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
            formatter.currencyCode = currencyFormatter.currencyCode
            formatter.currencySymbol = currencyFormatter.currencySymbol
            formatter.internationalCurrencySymbol = currencyFormatter.internationalCurrencySymbol
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = currencyFormatter.minimumFractionDigits
            return formatter
        }
    }
}

// this might better belong in a network service rather than in the view controller

private extension CurrencyExchangeViewController {
    func fetchExchangeRates(for inputCurrencyCode: String, completion: @escaping (Result<ExchangeRateResponse>) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=\(inputCurrencyCode)").response { response in
            guard response.error == nil, let data = response.data else {
                completion(.failure(response.error ?? CurrencyExchangeError.unknownNetworkError(response.data, response.response)))
                return
            }

            do {
                let exchangeRates = try JSONDecoder().decode(ExchangeRateResponse.self, from: data)
                if let error = exchangeRates.error {
                    completion(.failure(CurrencyExchangeError.webServiceError(error)))
                } else {
                    completion(.success(exchangeRates))
                }
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As indicated in the comments above, I’d probably move some of that stuff in the extensions into different objects, but I suspect even the above changes are a bit much to take in at one time, so I’ve stopped my refactoring there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is so detailed I will need some time to fully comprehend all the information. This exceeded my expectations!

Answer (score 3):

You need a completion handler in `assignOutput()`, I added also the minimum error handling to avoid crashes

```
//Variables
var inputCurrency = ""
var currencyCNY = 0.0
var currencyEUR = 0.0
var currencyGBP = 0.0
var currencyJPY = 0.0

@IBAction func btnConvert(_ sender: Any) {
    assignOutput() { success in 
        if success {
            if txtValue.text!.isEmpty {
                self.lblCurrency.text = "Please insert value"
            } else {
                if let inputValue = Double(txtValue.text!) { 
                    if segOutputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex == 0  {
                        let output = Double(inputValue * currencyCNY)
                        self.lblCurrency.text = "\(output)¥"
                    }  else if  segOutputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                        let output = Double(inputValue * currencyEUR)
                        self.lblCurrency.text = "\(output)€"
                    }  else if  segOutputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                        let output = Double(inputValue * currencyGBP)
                        self.lblCurrency.text = "\(output)"
                    } else if  segOutputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
                        let output = Double(inputValue * currencyJPY)
                        self.lblCurrency.text = "\(output)"
                    }
                } else {
                   self.lblCurrency.text = "Please enter a number"
                }
           }
        } else {
            self.lblCurrency.text = "Could not receive the exchange rates"
        }
    }
}

func assignOutput(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let currencies = ["EUR", "JPY",  "CNY", "USD"]
    inputCurrency = currencies[segInputCurrency.selectedSegmentIndex]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=\(inputCurrency)").responseJSON { (response) in
        if let result = response.result.value {
            let jsonCurrencies = JSON(result)
            let dictContent = jsonCurrencies["rates"]
            self.currencyCNY = dictContent["CNY"].double
            self.currencyEUR = dictContent["EUR"].double
            self.currencyGBP = dictContent["GBP"].double
            self.currencyJPY = dictContent["JPY"].double
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code. However, I am not quite sure why I need a completion handler and how to do this...

Comment: I updated the answer. You need a completion handler if there is an asynchronous task like the Alamofire request.

Comment: @Jakob Create a struct for currency with name, value, symbol properties. Then create array of currency objects

Comment: @vadian unfortunately Xcode now throws the following error: Expected parameter type following ':'

Comment: My bad, remove the colon after `@escaping`

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I will try this in a separate file... still learning the basics